# how to install Lasagne package with python con windows

Tags: python, package, neural-network

I'm new on python and I'm running some script on python 3.4. I'm getting the following error:

> ImportError: No module named 'lasagne'. Does someone know how to install this package on Python please?

Comment: i found useful information on joseripla link but need to face further issues before to complete the installation. I report hereafter the complete steps to install correctly Lasagne module:   [git app] (git-scm.com/download/win) and install git<br/>download Lasagne source: 'git clone github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne.git'<br/>download '.whl' at [scipy C.golhke pre-built Windows installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)<br/>install scipy 'pip install <your wheel>.whl'<br/>Install dependencies 'pip install -r Lasagne\requirements.txt'<br/> 'python Lasagne\setup.py install'.u've done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install from Pypi

```
pip install Lasagne
```

Here's the official [docs](http://lasagne.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/installation.html#install-from-pypi) from lasagne.

Comment: getting the following error:   'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Lasagne (from versions
: )
No matching distribution found for Lasagne'

Comment: following the useful link you reported i found the following procedure that works:

Comment: following the useful link you reported i found the following procedure that works: download git for windows at the following [http://git-scm.com/download/win] and install git , perform the following tasks: 'git clone https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne.git' from comand line. After successful completion of the 'clone' comand this last comand performs Lasagne installation 'pip install -r Lasagne\requirements.txt'

Answer (score 0):

See the Installation page:

http://lasagne.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/installation.html

> Lasagne hasn’t been released as of now. The only way to install it for now is from source.

So only installing from source seems to be supported, which is also described on that page.